# PostgreSQL: joining on jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, json

Using this contrived example structure:

**Base table data**

```
{
  "uid": "b12345",
  "nested": ["n12345", "n34567"]
}
```

**Nested table data**

```
[
  { "uid": "n12345", "message": "Hello world" },
  { "uid": "n34567", "message": "Hello world" }
]
```

I'm trying to join the tables on the `nested` array such that each uid is replaced with its corresponding record:

```
{
  "uid": "b12345",
  "nested": [
    { "uid": "n12345", "message": "Hello world" },
    { "uid": "n34567", "message": "Hello world" }
  ]
}
```

The solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413861/how-to-join-jsonb-array-elements-in-postgres) looks very close to what I need, but it seems like the main difference/blocker is that the `nested` array here is initially flat.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ef654e/3) is the SQL I've been using to test it, including a query closely modeled on the above post. I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: It's also worth thinking about _why_ you have nested IDs, and if you could design your tables to take advantage of relational features directly. Meaning, without a lot of unseating, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
select jsonb_build_object('uid', b.uid, 'nested', jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(m)))
from base b
  join lateral (
    select n.uid, n.message
    from nested n
      join jsonb_array_elements_text(b.nested) as x(bid) on x.bid = n.uid
  ) m on true
group by b.uid  
order by b.uid;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/ASA37564